# Rails new migrations not updating old data

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite, migration, sti

I have a model called Article. This model has attribute called duration which is a string. The duration can be morning, afternoon, evening and night.

For example, article object looks like this:

```
#<Article id: 1, created_at: "2015-09-22 08:00:08", updated_at: "2015-09-22 08:00:08", duration: "morning">
```

Since the duration has similar properties, I create a base class called duration and the inherited classes as morning, afternoon, evening and night.

In a duration there can be many articles. But a single article can have only one duration. So, I have `has_many` and `belongs_to` association:

```
app/model/duration.rb
class Duration < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

app/model/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :duration
end
```

Other inherited classes are:

```
app/model/duration/morning.rb
class Morning < Duration
end
```

and so on for `afternoon.rb`, `evening.rb` and `night.rb`.

I already have the migration to create durations table. To add the field `type` to duration, I have a migration called `add_type_to_duration.rb`

```
AddTypeToDuration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :durations, :type, :string
  end 
end
```

I have another migration file called `add_duration_ref_to_articles.rb` to add reference

```
class AddDurationRefToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :articles, :duration, index:true
  end
end
```

I have another migration to create the new durations in add_initial_durations.rb

```
class AddInitialDurations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    Morning.create
    Afternoon.create
    Evening.create
    Night.create 
  end
end
```

Now I want to update the old data to adapt according to new migrations. So, I have another migration called `update_articles_to_have_duration.rb`

```
class UpdateArticlesToHaveDuration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    morning = Duration.find_by_type("Morning")
    Article.where(duration: "morning").find_each do |article|
      article.update!(duration_id: morning.id)
    end
  end
end
```

Now when I run the migrations all the articles, that had `duration = morning`, now have `duration_id = nil`. However, when I run the last migration again with `rake db:migrate:redo step:1`, then articles have correct duration_id. I think somehow the migration is not run properly. However, I don't get any error while running them. Can anyone please let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: so, all in all everything works, right?

Comment: Yes everything works only if I run the migration to update the old articles once again. It doesn't work when I run the migration once. However, the problem is I also want to remove the attribute "duration" from Article.

Comment: just run all the migrations adding `duration_id` and then create a migration to remove the column `duration`

Comment: That is my problem. I have added duration_id to articles and when  running the migration to update old data to have duration_id, the duration_id is set to nil.

Comment: But you've said it is being set properly when run migration second time, or did i get something wrong?

Comment: You are completely right. But, I really don't want to mess up my migration on the production server. I want to run the migrations and update the old data all at one run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've said that `duration_id` is set properly when running the migration second time, the only reason why it's not working on the first go might be that the migrations are not running sequentially as you've shown.

Migration files have **timestamps** on them and they run oldest first when you do `rake db:migrate`.
See the timestamps of the migration file to ensure that they're ordered as you want them.

```
❯ rake db:migrate:status                                                                                                 

database: ~/blog/db/development.sqlite3

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20150907015616  Create articles
  down    20150907031746  Create comments
  down    20150909034614  Devise create users
```

You can use above command to see the *Migration Id* and copy it to run the migrations one after another to verify my assumption with following command:

```
❯ bin/rake db:migrate VERSION=20150907015616 VERSION=20150907031746 VERSION=20150909034614
```

You'll have to re-order(better to delete and recreate) the migration files or transpose its contents if the migration files do not follow the chronological order of timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it using `MyModel.reset_column_information`

```
class UpdateArticlesToHaveDuration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    Article.reset_column_information

    morning = Duration.find_by_type("Morning")
    Article.where(duration: "morning").find_each do |article|
      article.update!(duration_id: morning.id)
    end
  end
end
```

It resets all the cached information about columns, which will cause them to be reloaded on the next request.

The most common usage pattern for this method is probably in a migration, when just after creating a table you want to populate it with some default values

For more details, you can refer to the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/reset_column_information).